# What are the information represented by echo the topic of camera_info and image_raw?

Tags: ros, ros2, image-raw, camera-info, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using a multi camera plugin with SDF and the left and right images are published well in Rviz2. I wish to know the depth/distance of the object from the camera based on the images produced hence I try to echo the topic of camera_info and image_raw.
For camera_info, I get:
d :

- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0

k:

- 476.703...
- 0.0
- 400.5
- 0.0
- 476.703...
- 400.5
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0

r:

- 1.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0

p:

- same as k

while for image_raw topic, i get number range from 153 to 158.

May i know what are all these information means? And how can I use these information for my purpose to identify the distance of object?

Thank you in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392343/what-are-the-information-represented-by-echo-the-topic-of-camera_info-and-image_raw?/) by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there are three main topics advertised in most RGBD cameras:

- `camera_info` displays information related to the camera itself, like the size of the image and those parameters that "calibrate" it
- `image_raw` is the image itself, like the name suggests. Each number corresponds to pixel intensity
- `depth/points` is the one you are interested, as it displays the distance for each reading. You can also view this topic in rviz

If you want, I made explaining the topics from a depth camera:
https://youtu.be/G0U-s0KOqa0

---

Originally posted by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) with karma: 156 on 2021-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on 2021-12-29**:
Hi thank you so much for the explanation video. May I know what is the plugin that you're using in the video?